# Hide action from list settings

Tags: 2010, custom-actions, custom-action

I want to hide/disable/remove the link **`Form settings`** from all lists in my site collection.
How do I go about this?

[image]

I think I can do this on a per site basis using `HideCustomAction` but I don't know what the `Id` and `HideActionId` of this is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that with HideCustomAction.

You can get GroupId and HideActionId from the action itself.

The custom action is as below (taken from C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\FEATURES\IPFSSiteFeatures\FormSettings.xml)

```
<CustomAction
    Id="IPFSSettingsListEditPage"
    RegistrationType="List"
    GroupId="GeneralSettings"
    Location="Microsoft.SharePoint.ListEdit"
    Sequence="230"
    Title="$Resources:ipfscore,FormSettingsTitle;"
    >
    <UrlAction Url="~site/_layouts/FormSettings.aspx?List={ListId}&amp;Source={Source}"/>
</CustomAction>
```

So your HideCustomAction should be:

```
<HideCustomAction
      GroupId = "GeneralSettings"
      HideActionId = "IPFSSettingsListEditPage"
      Id = "HideFormSettings" //or any other unique text as ID for this HideCustomAction
      Location = "Microsoft.SharePoint.ListEdit">
</HideCustomAction>
```

Comment: Ah! That's what I thought. I saw `IPFSSettingsListEditPage` mentioned when I went 'Inspect Element' but I wasn't sure if this was the ID. Thanks!

Comment: But wouldn't that change on the server hide the action for all sites in the farm, not just one site collection?

Comment: @teylyn, No, for example HideCustomAction can be deployed with a Site or Web scoped feature and will hide the action only on the Site/Web where the feature is activated.

Comment: @Naim, thanks, that makes sense. I don't do code, so I don't encourage changes in the 14 hive, since most of the changes there apply to the whole farm. But this seems to be different. I can now see that it only applies to sites that use the feature. Thanks for that.